# How to run thermald with option --ignore-cpuid-check

Tags: kernel-modules, cpu, sensors

I get the message:

```
thermald: Unsupported cpu model, use thermal-conf.xml file or run with --ignore-cpuid-check
```

`sensors-detect` suggests `coretemp` and `w83627hf` which are installed and in `/etc/module`.

1. Try

If I run `sudo thermald --no-daemon --ignore-cpuid-check | tee thermald.log`, I get:

```
NO RAPL sysfs present
Polling mode is enabled: 4
```

2. Try

I change the `thermal-conf.xml` to the example [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues). Running `sudo thermald --no-daemon  | tee thermald.log` and I get:

```
NO RAPL sysfs present
10 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:f:6 (6:15:6)
 Need Linux PowerCap sysfs
Unsupported cpu model, using thermal-conf.xml only
Polling mode is enabled: 4
sensor id 2: No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
XML zone: invalid sensor type pkg-temp-0
Zone update failed: unable to bind
```

Therefore, the easiest way seems to run thermald with the option `--ignore-cpuid-check`. How can I run thermald with the option `--ignore-cpuid-check`? Or is there another way to get the prober xml configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If using systemd

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/thermald.service` by running

```
sudo systemctl edit --full thermald.service
```

Add the option at the end of `ExecStart`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Thermal Daemon Service

[Service]
Type=dbus
SuccessExitStatus=1
BusName=org.freedesktop.thermald
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service
```

### If using upstart ([below Ubuntu 15.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes))

In Ubuntu, you can add the option in `/etc/init/thermald.conf`:

```
# thermald - thermal daemon
# Upstart configuration file
# Manages platform thermals

description     "thermal daemon"

start on runlevel [2345] and started dbus
stop on stopping dbus

#
# don't respawn on error
#
normal exit 1

respawn

#
# consider something wrong if respawned 10 times in 1 minute
#
respawn limit 10 60

exec thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
```

Add the option in the last line.

Comment: Why `exec thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable`? Shouldn't it be normally run as daemon?

Comment: edit the systemd service file as you suggested leads to the service file been overwritten at the first package update.
to avert this problem you can use `systemctl edit --full thermald`